# JavaFx ObservableList<String> sorted() vs sorted(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder())

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

So I originally tried using

```
listOfStrings = listOfStrings.sorted();


Ordering user11, user10, user20, user04 etc...
```

Which has [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#sorted--) that states it will create a list with **natural ordering**

User complained about the ordering so I thought I would have to write a comparator but by luck IntelliJ auto filled in

```
listOfStrings = listOfStrings.sorted(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder());

Ordering user01, user02, user03, user04 etc...
```

My first thought was that it would return the same thing but it sorts the Strings like I want.  The documentation for [Comparator.naturalOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) also  **natural order**.

So what did I miss in the documentation?

My reading of the documentation leads me to believe they should order the list the same.  Does anyone understand why they don't?

Strings are being read in from a text file 
user01,user02,user03.user04,user05,user06,user07,user08,user09,user10,user11,user12,user13,user14,user15,user16,user17,user18,user19,user20
used as keys in has map.

```
for (String user: userMap.keySet()) {
            listOfStrings.add(user);
}  

// listOfStrings = listOfStrings.sorted();  //
listOfStrings = listOfStrings.sorted(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder());
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the two different ordering schemes?

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example when the results are different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug in Java 8u40 which has subsequently been (mostly) fixed for later releases.  (See the comments on this answer for a discussion of edge cases or alternate implementation choices).

The bug tracker issue:

- [JDK-8094532 ObservableList.sorted() does nothing](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094532)

and the [associated changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/rev/ec4a27aae432).

---

The [Java 8u40 code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/tip/modules/base/src/main/java8/javafx/collections/ObservableList.java#l133) in `ObservableList.java` is:

```
public default SortedList<E> sorted() {
    return sorted(null);
}
```

The erroneous call sequence for the above call is detailed in user pbabcdefp's answer.  The error in the code basically means the `sorted()` method doesn't return a sorted list at all, but instead returns the list in the current order it is in.

The [Java 8u-dev](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/base/src/main/java8/javafx/collections/ObservableList.java#l134) (current trunk code) and [Java 9u-dev](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9-dev/rt/file/tip/modules/base/src/main/java8/javafx/collections/ObservableList.java#l134) code is:

```
/**
 * Creates a {@link SortedList} wrapper of this list with the natural
 * ordering.
 * @return new {@code SortedList}
 * @since JavaFX 8.0
 */
public default SortedList<E> sorted() {
    Comparator naturalOrder = new Comparator<E>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(E o1, E o2) {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (o1 == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }

            if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
                return ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
            }

            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1.toString(), o2.toString());
        }
    };
    return sorted(naturalOrder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the bug tracker. Even the new version looks a bit dodgy to me. Ignoring the use of raw types, it isn't even symmetric. If `E` is `Object`, `o1` is `"Foo"` and `o2` is `new Object()` then `compare(o1, o2)` will throw a `ClassCastException` while `compare(o2, o1)` will compare the `toString` representations. `if(o1 instanceof Comparable && o2 instanceof Comparable)` seems more logical.

Comment: My question about there fix was couldn't they just use Comparator.<String>naturalOrder(); like I kinda did to work instead of writing it over?

Comment: Travis, I suggest you create a new issue in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39807) to have a developer take a look into it to see if a superior solution should be implemented along either the direction that pbabcdefp or yourself suggest - you can just link back to this stackoverflow issue from the issue report.

Comment: @ pbabcdefp: in which line do you think will an `ClassCastException` occur, when `E` is `Object` and `o1` is typeof `Foo` and `o2` is `new Object()`? Both parameter-values are (in the end) of type `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

My reading of the docs is also that you should get the same order for both calls. However this is what I have found by looking at the source code.

Here is the source code for `ObservableList.sorted()`

```
public default SortedList<E> sorted() {
    return sorted(null);
}
```

and here is the method called.

```
public default SortedList<E> sorted(Comparator<E> comparator) {
    return new SortedList<>(this, comparator);
}
```

Here are the docs for the relevant constructor.

> ```
> public SortedList(ObservableList<? extends E> source,
>               Comparator<? super E> comparator)
> ```
>
> Creates a new SortedList wrapped around the source list. The source list will be sorted using the comparator provided. If null is provided, the list stays unordered and is equal to the source list.

So as far as I can tell, the code contradicts the documentation, unless an implementation of `ObservableList` overrides the relevant default method. Very strange. It must be a bug, surely?

Comment: I was wondering if it was a bug myself but 9 times 10 when its a tool that well used like Java I find I usually misunderstood something.

Comment: @Travis. Same here. I hesitated before adding the last sentence. This really is very odd.